# Gensim get topic for a document (seen document)

Tags: python, lda, gensim

I know that after training the lda model for gensim, we can get the topic for an unseen document by:

```
lda = LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=10)
doc_lda = lda[doc_bow]
```

But how about the documents that are already used for training? I mean is there a way to get the topic for a document in corpus that was used in training without treating it like a new document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Information from individual documents is distilled into the model, then forgotten. 
No per-document information is kept (more generally: no information that would require `O(#docs)` memory is kept).

Comment: But if I want to get the topic distribution for the trained document, so I can have some kind of clustering operation, then what I can do?